# Is `subscriber` object just a wrapper for the `observer ` object

Tags: javascript, rxjs

In the following code, is the `subscriber` object in the anonymous function call in `new Observable(function(subscriber)` a wrapper for the `observer` object?

```
const observer = {
    next: (data: any) => console.log('Observer got a next value: ', data),
    error: (err: any) => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
    complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'),
  };      
  const observable = new Observable(function(subscriber)  {
    subscriber.next(1);
    subscriber.next(2);
    subscriber.next(3);
    setTimeout(() => {
      subscriber.next(4);
      subscriber.complete();
    }, 1000);
  });
observable.subscribe(observer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subscriber` in `function(subscriber)  {...}` is the name of the parameter of the function which is invoked when the `subscribe` method is called on the `observable`.

Let's see step by step.

First you create the Observable like this

```
new Observable(function(subscriber)  {...})
```

What you are doing is you are passing a function to the constructor method. That function is stored in the `observable` instance you have created.

Then you invoke the `subscribe` function on the observable you have created above like this

```
observable.subscribe(observer)
```

What you do here is to ask the `observable` to execute the function passed at construction time with the `observer` as value of the parameter. `observer` in this case is an object of type `Observer`.

Answer (score 0):

The observer and subscriber are the same type of object (in typescript they'd have the same interface).

The observer is being defined in code. The subscriber is a parameter.

Consider

`a: number = 10;` vs `function(b:number){...`

We know the value of `a`, but `b` doesn't have q concrete value until the function is called. In fact, you could call this function with the value in `a`. `a` does not wrap `b` as such.